# implicit declaration of function ‘NewByteArray’

Tags: java, c, jni

Хочу проверить будет ли освобождать в java память, выделенную в си или c++. Как я понял что надо использовать функцию NewByteArray, и она есть в jni.h. Но почему то компилятор пишет что неизвестная функция. Вот код jni.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Main.h"

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_Main_get_1byte ( JNIEnv *env, jobject obj ) {
        jbyteArray test = NewByteArray ( env, 255 );

        return test;
}
```

Вот код Main.

```
1 import java.io.*;
  2 
  3 class Main {
  4         private native byte[] get_byte();
  5 
  6         public static void main ( String[] args ) {
  7 
  8                 Console cons = System.console();
  9                 String pwd;
 10                 while ( true ) {
 11                         pwd = cons.readLine ( );
 12                         byte[] test = new Main().get_byte ( );
 13 
 14                         pwd = cons.readLine ( );
 15                         test[0] = '1';
 16                         System.out.println ( "Новый цикл." );
 17 
 18                 }
 19         }
 20 
 21         static {
 22                 System.loadLibrary ( "Main" );
 23         }
 24 }
```

Comment: Тут все будет неизвестное, ведь `jni.h` не подключен. А вызвать надо через указатель `env->NewByteArray(...`

Comment: `jni.h` подключен в `Main.h`

Answer (score 0):

Надо писать так.

```
(*env)->NewByteArray ( env, 255 );
```